# Node.js (with socket.io and express) throw "events.js:71 throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event"

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm running express (via nginx proxy) with socket.io and after few moments (app for some time works fine) console throw this:

```
events.js:71
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1360:15)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._writeRaw (http.js:507:26)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage._send (http.js:476:15)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (http.js:749:16)
    at XHRPolling.doWrite (/home/xyz/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/xhr-polling.js:67:17)
    at XHRPolling.HTTPPolling.write (/home/xyz/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/http-polling.js:132:8)
    at XHRPolling.Transport.onDispatch (/home/xyz/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:222:10)
    at Socket.dispatch (/home/xyz/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:230:38)
    at Socket.packet (/home/xyz/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:214:10)
    at Socket.emit (/home/xyz/chat/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:368:15)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It means that there is an error, maybe at connecting time, and you don't have a handler for that. Can we see the code you are using to setup socket.io ??

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039089/my-node-js-app-is-getting-an-unhandled-error-event-randomly-on-writing-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using node.js version 0.8.20, then this bug was observed by many including myself.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1160

Upgrading node.js to version 0.8.21 solves this problem.

Comment: @otmezger this particular issue happened due to the fix in 0.8.20 (http: Raise hangup error on destroyed socket write) and upgrading node to 0.8.21 had solved this issue for me and as reported by others (https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/issues/1541). May be you can try out 0.8.19 or above 0.8.21 to double check.

Comment: it can be. I found an error elsewhere. now it is gone. It was not the same issue.